# Force GNU AS to use alternative

Tags: assembly, arm, disassembly

I have a ARM binary and some assembly code.
The disassembly from the binary reads

`1e40 -> subs r0,r0,#1`

The instructions from the assembly code read the same.
(The code uses the `.syntax unified` directive)

However when I use GNU AS (From the gcc toolchain from ARM 2017 Q4),
it evaluates

`subs r0,r0,#1` to

`3801-> subs r0,#1`

using objdump

I guess those two are probably the same, however I'd still like to know if there is a way to chose the generation of the first opcode over the second, as I believe it causes issues on the device I'm using.

Comment: Erm, `objdump` is responsible for its own output...

Comment: You can force the generation of the first opcode by writing `.short 0x401e`.

Comment: I kind of hoped there is an option or a certain mnemonic to force that.
But thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You did not state the architecture, but as it is apparently Thumb, I will use the Cortex-M as basis.

Consulting the "ARMv7-M Application Level Architecture Reference Manual", the op-code can be decoded easily. Try it, it's a good practice and always a good idea to keep it nearby when writing machine-level code.

They are actually two different instructions, but with the same effect.

The first op-code refers to a dual-register (source, destination) operation with a small 3 bit immediate (zero extended, range 0…7). Here, both registers happen to be the same register, making it effectively a single-register decrement.

The second is a single register subtraction with an 8 bit immediate operand (zero extended, range 0…255). It is not clear why you get two different variants, but they should make no actual difference (at least for the Cortex-M4 both take one clock and I'd be surprised if other architectures had different values).

So the disassembly reflects the acual instruction. gas seems to convert the original two-register instruction to the single-register op-code.

Note there are various operations which could result in different op-codes. For the information given, it is not clear why they were choosen. Imo, the second is more reasonable, the first makes only sense if there are two different registers involved.

If there are problems with your code, it is most unlikely it's this instruction. Maybe it's time to start the debugger.

Comment: Thank you.
I was indeed refering to the Cortex-M.
It's good to hear that the problem is probably somewhere else.

I hoped there was a way to avoid GAS from converting the two-register instruction to a single-register opcode.

Comment: @The19thFighter: As I interpret UAL, the assembler is free to use any of both. **Iff** there was any problem, it would be the other way 'round. But I can assure you there is no problem with this op-code for code-execution. Of course if you use dirty hackish-tricks like self-modifying code, etc, things might be different. Please remember to upvote and/accept if the answer is satisfying.

Answer (score 3):

Just try it...

so.s

```
.thumb
sub r0,#1
.syntax unified
subs r0,r0,#1
sub r0,#1
subs.n r0,#1
```

assemble and disassemble

```
arm-none-eabi-as so.s -o so.o
arm-none-eabi-objdump -D so.o

so.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <.text>:
   0:   3801        subs    r0, #1
   2:   3801        subs    r0, #1
   4:   f1a0 0001   sub.w   r0, r0, #1
   8:   3801        subs    r0, #1
```

EDIT to Olaf's comment.

```
.thumb
sub r0,#1
sub r0,r0,#1
sub r1,r2,#1
.syntax unified
subs r0,r0,#1
sub r0,#1
subs.n r0,#1
subs.n r0,r0,#1
subs r1,r2,#1


00000000 <.text>:
   0:   3801        subs    r0, #1
   2:   3801        subs    r0, #1
   4:   1e51        subs    r1, r2, #1
   6:   3801        subs    r0, #1
   8:   f1a0 0001   sub.w   r0, r0, #1
   c:   3801        subs    r0, #1
   e:   3801        subs    r0, #1
  10:   1e51        subs    r1, r2, #1
```

I/you/we would have to dig into the assembler source to see if there is a way around this.  Fuz may have the simplest answer.  Likely that the assembler optimized to the one with more flexibility in the immediate.  You could certainly remove that optimization/feature (if there isnt a flag).

EDIT2

Perhaps this is it.

```
#define T_OPCODE_SUB_I8 0x3800
#define T_OPCODE_SUB_I3 0x1e00

    else if (rs == rd)
      {
        if (value & ~0xff)
          as_bad_where (fixP->fx_file, fixP->fx_line,
                _("immediate value out of range"));
        newval = subtract ? T_OPCODE_SUB_I8 : T_OPCODE_ADD_I8;
        newval |= (rd << 8) | value;
      }
    else
      {
        if (value & ~0x7)
          as_bad_where (fixP->fx_file, fixP->fx_line,
                _("immediate value out of range"));
        newval = subtract ? T_OPCODE_SUB_I3 : T_OPCODE_ADD_I3;
        newval |= rd | (rs << 3) | (value << 6);
      }
```

If you add this

```
else if (value & ~0x7)
  {
    newval = subtract ? T_OPCODE_SUB_I3 : T_OPCODE_ADD_I3;
    newval |= rd | (rs << 3) | (value << 6);
  }
```

in front of

```
else if (rs == rd)
```

then

```
.cpu cortex-m7
.thumb
sub r0,r0,#15
sub r0,r0,#1
.syntax unified
subs.n r0,r0,#1
subs.n r0,r0,#15
```

gives the desired result.

```
   0:   1fc0        subs    r0, r0, #7
   2:   3801        subs    r0, #1
   4:   3801        subs    r0, #1
   6:   1fc0        subs    r0, r0, #7
```

So I think that rs == rd is preventing you from generating the instruction you want.

EDIT 3

binutils 2.7 does not have this define T_OPCODE_SUB_I8 so perhaps does not have thumb support, didnt dig deeper than that.  binutils 2.8 does and also includes this optimization.  So as far back as 1997 this has been there.  If you want to generate the instruction in question with gnu assembler it appears you need to modify gnu assembler...

Comment: That does not explain how to generate the three-operand 16-bit op-code. Not that it would be necessary. The Thumb2 32 bit op-code results from not updating the condition codes. There is also a 32 bit `subs` variant, which should be enforcable with `subs.w`, but it seems not possible to get the `subs rd,rs,imm3` op-code (`0x1e40` for the example).

Comment: Btw: there is no 16 bit `sub` op-code. `sub` translated to the `subs` op-code looks strange to me. There should be a preceeding `IT` for the first instruction to suppress updating the CCR.

Comment: @olaf, I know thats the fun of assembly language, each assembler has its own.   gnu assembler for whatever reason doesnt let you use subs traditionally, but objdump would disassemble it correctly as subs.  The unified syntax is a bit of a failure as it creates more pain that it solves.  So you have to do these kinds of things to figure it out...The unified syntax at least as defined by gnu assembler has made it difficult to get specific instructions without .inst.

Comment: The IT block note in the armv7 is perhaps specific to armv7, back to armv4t it was just one of the subtracts.  The armv7 docs also state all thumb variants.

Comment: If it were specifically required inside an IT block, then the assembler should generate an error when an armv7 variant is specified.

Comment: I don't see a problem with gas using the single-register variant where possible. It does not change the behaviour nor does it cost more cycles. The only difference I can think of is it costs less cycle, i.e. can be folded with another instruction because of one less register read. But this is neither true on CM3 nor CM4 and I'd be surprised if on any other arch. It's basically the same with many other ARM instructions, e.g. `MOV`. (and it's true for `.thumb` mode, too apparently.

Comment: Both 16 bit op-codes are actually Thumb1, so the redundancy exists since the first version (IIRC ARMv5T, 32 bit ARM mode is unrelated here). Btw. this problem is known for many other processors, expecially with an orthogonal instruction set. Maybe the conversion to `SUBS` in `.thumb` mode is legal? I never used that legacy. Imo gas should prefix with `IT AL` automatically. IIRC `IT` can take zero cycles under certain conditions (can't find the referrence, though) - not counting the memory access to read the op-code, of course.

Comment: `sub r0,r0,#15` should not give `subs    r0, r0, #7`. Mostly because of the different immediate value. IMO there is something wrong with your files/setup/toolchain.